# when cell gets selected in table view i should able to animate the cell before going to another view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.type = @"suckEffect";
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.delegate = self;
animation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];
```

Can any body tell me what are the other types of animations to animate the table cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am selected one of these to animate rows ,tat solved my problem....

```
pageCurl, 
pageUnCurl, 
suckEffect, 
spewEffect,
cameraIris (from the Photos application),
cameraIrisHollowOpen,
cameraIrisHollowClose,
genieEffect (typically used for deleting garbage),
unGenieEffect, 
rippleEffect, 
twist, 
tubey,
swirl,
charminUltra,
zoomyIn,
zoomyOut,
oglFlip.
```